# wordpressをインストールしているサーバーのPHPを7.3から8.0に更新したら503エラーになってしまう

Tags: php, apache

CentOS 7
Apache 2.4.6 ＆ (mod)php7.3.3

上記環境から表題のとおりPHPを8.0に更新をしたら503エラーが表示されるようになってしまいました。
Apacheやサーバーの再起動もしてみましたが解決せず、エラーログを見たところ下記のようなエラーをはいていました。

```
[proxy:error] [pid 2370] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9073 (*) failed

[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2370] [client ***.***.***.**:*****] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

色々調べていると「php-fpm」の設定変更や再起動したら良いという記事が多かったのですが「php-fpm」を使用していない為、どうしたら良いのかが分からずここで質問をさせて頂きました。

何卒お知恵をお借りできればと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の経験のもとにして、php-fpmをインストールしなければならないと思います.CentOS7なので下記の記事を参考してください.

#4を実行するときPHPのバージョンを見てください。

```
php -v
```

参考　https://shouts.dev/articles/install-latest-php-php-fpm-on-centos-7

Comment: おっしゃる通り「php-fpm」のインストールで直りました！
本当にありがとうございます！